# ChromeDriver.exe does not exist when running on teamcity

Tags: selenium-webdriver, teamcity, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-iedriver

I have created 3 Test Server, IE, Chrome and Firefox.
In TeamCity i created 3 build configuration IE, Chrome and Firefox.
I have 3 Agents AgentIE, AgentChrome and AgentFirefox.

Each agent is assign to specific build configuration example Build Configuration IE is to AgentIE

When i run the Build Configuration Firefox, all tests gets executed but when i run the Build Configuration IE and Chrome tests do not get executed .
Error message indicate that the IE and Chrome exe do not exist but i followed the exe file exist in the directory and in a directory on the PATH environment variable.

MSTest]

```
Framework.FeatureFiles.AdditionalFieldsFeature.CreateNewAdditionalField_0001 (Create New Additional Field: 0001)

[10:35:53][Framework.FeatureFiles.AdditionalFieldsFeature.CreateNewAdditionalField_0001 (Create New Additional Field: 0001)] Assembly Initialization method Framework.BaseClasses.Base.InitWebdriver threw exception. OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.. Aborting test execution.

[10:35:53][Framework.FeatureFiles.AdditionalFieldsFeature.CreateNewAdditionalField_0001 (Create New Additional Field: 0001)] at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.FindDriverServiceExecutable(String executableName, Uri downloadUrl)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
at Framework.BaseClasses.Base.GetChromeDriver() in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\eba5cd3c0056fc6a\Framework\BaseClasses\Base.cs:line 61
at Framework.BaseClasses.Base.InitWebdriver(TestContext tc) in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\eba5cd3c0056fc6a\Framework\BaseClasses\Base.cs:line 84
```

If i run the Chrome build configuration on a agent that is running on the teamcity server, the test gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and I was able to resolve it by doing the following steps:

- You need to download the chromedriver.exe for your machine type.
- Then put the folder where you save the chromedriver.exe in the Path
  variable of the TeamCity server.
- Next you need to restart the
  TeamCity server.

You can download [the latest Chrome Driver here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

[Here are some instructions on how to add variable to the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows).

Comment: From the message, it was clear that I needed to add to the PATH, but restarting the TeamCity server was the key step that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the path variable on the specific machine.